# Why is sorting a string O(n log n)?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Plain English explanation of Big O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o)

In the answer to a programming puzzle, it said `sorting a string takes  O(n log n) time`.
How is that derived?

Does anybody have a good reference link for Big O resources?

Comment: How do you mean 'sorting a string'?  Do you mean sorting a list of strings?

Comment: Or maybe sorting characters in a string..

Comment: Its sorting characters in a string. I know what big O is, I don't know in particular why sorting characters in a string is n log n.

Answer (score 25):

> Why is sorting a string O(n log n)?

Sorting the characters in a string is not necessarily `O(n log n)`.

- `O(n log n)` is the **optimal** value for a [comparison sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort). It is also the complexity of many language's default sort implementation. However it's certainly possible to do worse than this. The complexity of sorting the characters in a string depends on the specific algorithm you choose to solve this task.
- It's also possible to do better than `O(n log n)` in some cases by using a sorting algorithm which is not a comparison sort. For example, if you know that you have an ASCII string with a maximum of 127 distinct characters you could use a [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) which is `O(n)`. A counting sort would also be feasible for Unicode strings where all characters are in the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

Answer (score 0):

A definition and some examples of Big O can be found by using a search engine, e.g. here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

An explanation of sort algorithms based on comparing elements, together with an explanation for the lower bound on the number of required comparisons, can be found here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort